# Javascript setTimeout in foreach: need help creating a closure

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

I have this function

```
notes.forEach(function(note) {          
    setTimeout(function() {
        playNote(note);
    }, 1000);
});
```

This doesn't work.  It plays all the notes at the same time, instead of playing them sequentially with a 1 second gap in between.  It looks like I need to have a closure here to make this work. Could someone help me fix this function so it would play the note with the delay between each note?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because all timeouts are set at the same time...

Do something like this:

```
playAllNotes(0);
function playAllNotes(index) {
    if(notes.length > index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            playNote(notes[index]);
            playAllNotes(++index);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question...this works, but if I add any other action along with playNote() it doesn't.  For example, if I addClass('playing') before playnote() and removeClass('playing') after playNote(), it plays all the notes, but the add/remove class happens only the first time.  It works in the debugger though...any thoughts?

Comment: you remove class "playing" from what? I don't have any code to understand this sry.

Comment: Never mind, it was showing and hiding the css very quickly to be noticeable to the human eye, so I added that in a setTimeout as well and now everything is fine.  Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to do this:

1) Have a function that grabs one note every second until there are no more notes:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  playNote(notes.shift()); // changes the notes array!
  if (!notes.length) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

2) Start all the timers at the same time with different delays:

```
notes.forEach(function(note, index) {
  setTimeout(playNote.bind(null, note), index*1000);
});
```

Comment: Smart and interesting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter, it's tricky but worth it if you are working with objects:

```
counter = 0;
$.each(object, function(index,item){
  counter++;
  var localCounter = counter;
  setTimeout(function{
   console.log('something')
  }, counter * 1000) // change one to number of milliseconds you need
})
```

First counter is global, so if we don't user `var localCounter` we would execute all timeouts at the same time.