# Multitple tasks in a setTimeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, closures, settimeout

I had asked a question earlier about a using setTimeout in a foreach using closures:
[Javascript setTimeout in foreach: need help creating a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904700/javascript-settimeout-in-foreach-need-help-creating-a-closure/21904850?noredirect=1#21904850)

The selected answer works for me however I have a different problem now.  Here is what I am trying to do:

```
playAllNotes(0);
function playAllNotes(index) {
    if(notes.length > index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('mydiv').addClass('playing-note');
            playNote(notes[index]);
            $('mydiv').removeClass('playing-note');
            playAllNotes(index++);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

The above code (without the add and remove class) works as expected--play the note every second.  However, what I wanted to do is to also change the color of a div when the note is playing, so I have the addclass before and removeclass after the playNote() method. The result is that the notes still play fine, but the css changing doesn't work--I think what's happening is that the add and remove are not going through the timeout logic, so it gets removed before I can notice it (because it actually does work in debugging mode).

I guess I don't completely understand how timeouts work, so I'd appreciate if anyone could help me fix the above code.

UPDATE:
playNote() uses the MIDI.js library to play a piano note:

```
function playNote(noteNumber){
  var velocity = 127;
  var delay = 0;
  var instrumentChannel= 0;  
  MIDI.noteOn(instrumentChannel, noteNumber, velocity, delay);  
}
```

Comment: What is "playNote()"?

Comment: @Pointy I'll update my question with what's in playNote()

Comment: If you add your fiddle then is easy to catch error..http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I suspect it is working, but is happening so quickly that you never see it.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Yes, I confirmed that's what is happening because it works in the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not related to timeout: it's related to the rendering engine behaviour.

HTML rendering is asynchronous: you add the `playing-note` class, but it won't be rendered immediately.

However, your code is synchronous: you immediately remove the `playing-note` class, and when the next render is applied... then nothing changed.

What you need is to add another timeout to delay the class removal, and give enought time for a human eye to notice the change.

For example:

```
playAllNotes(0);
function playAllNotes(index) {
    if(notes.length > index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('mydiv').addClass('playing-note');
            playNote(notes[index]);
            // let say 250ms is enought for people to notice the change.
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('mydiv').removeClass('playing-note');
            }, 250);
            playAllNotes(index++);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this :

```
 playAllNotes(0);
function playAllNotes(index) {
if(notes.length > index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('mydiv').addClass('playing-note');

        playNote(notes[index],index);

    }, 1000);
}
}

  function playNote(noteNumber,index){
  var velocity = 127; 
 var delay = 0; var instrumentChannel= 0;
 MIDI.noteOn(instrumentChannel, noteNumber, velocity, delay);

 $('mydiv').removeClass('playing-note');
playAllNotes(index++);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
playAllNotes(0);
function playAllNotes(index) {
    if(notes.length > index) {
        setTimeout(function() {

            $("mydiv").addClass("playing-note").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
                $(this).removeClass("playing-note");
                next();
            });

            playNote(notes[index]);
            playAllNotes(index++);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```